# How to disable Checkbox depending on another Checkbox?

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

On Java, is there any way to disable a checkbox (call it B), if checkbox A is checked.

When I say disable, the user can't check it off..Its setEditable(false) or something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`JCheckBox.setEnabled(false)`

A tutortial showing exactly that is here: [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
 final JCheckBox a = new JCheckBox();
 final JCheckBox b = new JCheckBox();
 a.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
  @Override
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
      b.setEnabled(a.isSelected());
    }
  }
 });
```

Comment: This answer may be a few years old, but it still helped me!

Answer (score 3):

yourCheckBox.setEnabled(false);

Answer (score 3):

or you can use ButtonGroup:

```
JCheckBox chkA = new JCheckBox();
JCheckBox chkB = new JCheckBox();
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(chkA);
group.add(chkB);
```